# SQL accepts multiple '+' while coding but doesn't produce a run-time error, why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

These lines of code:

```
DECLARE @counter  integer
SET @counter = 42
WHILE @counter < 52
BEGIN
    set @counter = @counter++++++++ 1
    PRINT 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char) 
END
```

Are the same as these (according to SSMS):

```
DECLARE @counter  integer
SET @counter = 42
WHILE @counter < 52
BEGIN 
    set @counter = @counter + 1
   PRINT 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char) 
END
```

Why doesn't SSMS care or take into account multiple `+`?

Comment: `+` is also a unary operator.  I think it does nothing.  But you can easily imagine 1-1, 1- -1, 1- -(-1) and so on.

Comment: See [unary operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188400.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The first plus will be interpreted as the add operation (add rvalue to lvalue and return the result). All subsequent plus signs will act as unary plus towards its rvalue, that is "return the value of the numeric expression that follows" - this can be chained:

```
+(+(+(+1)))
```

Which is pointless, but it is valid syntax.
It would be a different story if T-SQL defined an `x++` increment operator. No current version of T-SQL has that. `+=` and `-=` have been added as of SQL Server 2008, but `--` and `++` not.